# Limit of $\epsilon t-f(t)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $f(t)$ be continuously differentiable, increasing, positive and unbounded in $[0,\infty)$.

Assume that:

1. $\lim_{t \to \infty} t-f(t) =\infty$;
2. For any $\epsilon >0$, the function $\epsilon t-f(t)$  is unbounded from above.

Does 1. and 2.  implies that 
 $$\lim_{t \to \infty} \epsilon t-f(t) =\infty?$$

Thank you

Comment: Are you sure this a correct statement of the problem? If a function $\epsilon t - f(t)$ is unbounded on $[0, \infty]$ then your limit is infinite by definition of unbounded.

Comment: I think this also implies that $\underset {t \rightarrow \infty}{lim} f'(t) = 0$

Comment: This is the correct statement.  If the limit exists, it muset be $\infty$. the question is, if the limit exists at all.